# IProvideClassInfo for Visual Studio Add In for Properties Panel

Tags: visual-studio, propertygrid, visual-studio-addins

I am creating a Visual Studio Package for VS 2010 using VB.Net that contains a custom editor. The editor presents many items in ListViews. I want the item selected (its parent and any child items) to appear in the PropertyGrid panel object list to allow for property edits. I have this working. Normally the drop down list of selectable items appears with the name of the item in bold text followed by the type name for that object. In my package I cannot get the bold name to appear, only the type name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165752(v=vs.100).aspx

This page is the only piece of information I can find on naming an object in the object list. As the link states, I implemented IProvideClassInfo in the objects I'm giving to VS to display in the list but the GetClassInfo method is never called and no name is displayed. Each object also has a public property called "Name" as well just in case that worked. It did not.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Very vague.  If this is a .NET object you are displaying instead of a COM object then you need a TypeConverter to customize the way it is displayed.

Comment: Ok, everything I can find involving TypeConverters has nothing to do with this. I thought you were on to something because of the COM object thing. obj.GetType().isCOMObject returns false on all of my objects and I'm not sure how to make an object that actually is a COM object in VB.net. Microsoft has an article about it but it has a note saying they aren't "true" com objects so I'm still at a loss about this whole thing. It seems that no one has done this before. The default template that comes with the VS 2010 SP1 SDK doesn't do this correctly.

Comment: I even added a windows form, which appears correctly normally in the properties drop down into my own object list for the drop down and it doesn't display the name of the object either (though all the properties are seemingly the same)... which suggests that VS doesn't implement this feature the same way for internal objects and package objects. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the forum on MSDN I finally found someone answering this question.

IProvideClassInfo has nothing to do with this like the link I gave states. The correct answer is to implement the ICustomTypeDescriptor interface in your objects. Most of the function implementations involve returning the result of the same function call on the TypeDescriptor object (shared/static functions). The GetComponentName result will be the bold part of the drop down. The GetClassName result will be the non-bold part. I'm not sure what the GetEditor function does but returning the TypeDescriptor.GetEditor result causes an infinite loop, returning Nothing/null seems to work.

I created a base class for all my objects that will go into the Property panel's drop down that implements all the functions where GetClassName returns Me.GetType().Name and GetComponentName returns Me.ToString()

It works great.